# format of Windows type libraries?

Tags: windows, typelib

Where do I find a description of the format of Windows type libraries?

The format specification is probably somewhere at Microsoft but I haven't lucky so far.

Googling has not been successfull, too.

Comment: Use ITypeLib to read type libraries.  LoadTypeLib() is the factory method.  CreateTypeLib2() is you want to create one.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, hence I deleted my answer .